# Disable user typing text box c#

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

Is it possible to disable the user typing input text area in the V4 bot framework in any channel ? I have this as part of customer requirement Can someone please help me

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such functionality at this moment.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see the provided solution.

Comment: @StevenKanberg OP specified `Channel` could you please show a example for `Channel`? I know its possible in webchat, its because of `JavaScript`. So hope you would consider your words `This is incorrect`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The box you refer to is called the send box. If you are using [BotFramework-Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), you can disable it by passing the value via `styleOptions` like so:

```js
<script>
  (async function () {

    const styleOptions = {
      hideSendBox = true
    }

    [...]

    window.ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactWebChat
        directLine={directLine},
        styleOptions={styleOptions}
      />,
      document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
    );
  })
</script>
```

If you are using the iFrame embedded version of Web Chat, it is not configurable.

Hope of help!

---

### Edit

If you are wanting the send box to be responsive according to the type of activity received from the bot, then you will want to use a combination of the `activityMiddleware()` function as well as an event emitter/listener. In the following example, I am hiding/showing the send box when `suggestedActions` is an activity property.

Please be aware that the data values should be "none" and "flex". In particular, the latter value when it is not `suggestedActions` in order to maintain the current code.

```js
<script>
  (async function () {

    [...]

    const activityMiddleware = () => next => card => {
      const { activity: { suggestedActions } } = card;
      const toggleSendBoxEvent = new Event('ToggleSendBoxEvent')
      if (suggestedActions) {
        toggleSendBoxEvent.data = "none";
        window.dispatchEvent(toggleSendBoxEvent);
      } else {
        toggleSendBoxEvent.data = "flex";
        window.dispatchEvent(toggleSendBoxEvent);
      }
  
      return next(card);
    )

    [...]

    window.ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactWebChat
        directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }) }
        activityMiddleware={ activityMiddleware }
      />,
      document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
    );

    window.addEventListener('ToggleSendBoxEvent', ( { data } ) => {
      const sendBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
      let send_Box;
      for (let sendBox of sendBoxes) {
        send_Box = sendBox;
      }
      send_Box.setAttribute('style', `display:${ data }`)
    })

  });
</script>
```

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: but how can we hide the send box on specific conditions? like for example, I want the send box to be disable when my bot response have buttons/choices to select and the send box should be enable to answer bot for normal question. If you can help me with this also that would be really of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Updated the post to reflect how to conditionally show/hide the send box. Please upvote, if of use.

Comment: @StevenKanberg  can you please help me , what went wrong in my code, its not working for me, i used your solution , find my full code here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412674/how-to-hide-show-the-sendbox-whenever-the-bot-replies-with-the-suggested-actio

Answer (score 0):

This really works for me

```
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,react,stage-3">
  (async function () {
    const { ReactWebChat } = window.WebChat;
                    
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      const toggleSendBoxEvent = new Event('ToggleSendBoxEvent')
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
        toggleSendBoxEvent.data = "none";
        window.dispatchEvent(toggleSendBoxEvent);
      } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY_FULFILLED') {
        toggleSendBoxEvent.data = "flex";
        window.dispatchEvent(toggleSendBoxEvent);
      }
      return next(action);
    });

    
    window.ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactWebChat 
        directLine={window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: '<your token>' })}
        store={ store }
      />,
      document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
    
    window.addEventListener('ToggleSendBoxEvent', ( { data } ) => {
      const sendBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("webchat__send-box-text-box__input");
      let send_Box;
      for (let sendBox of sendBoxes) {
        send_Box = sendBox;
      }
      send_Box.setAttribute('style', `display:${ data }`)
    })
    
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));
</script>
```

Comment: Don't just paste a chunk of code, explain what is different, and why should use your solution